# How to filter NUnit tests by category using "dotnet test"

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, dotnet-cli

I have a project that has a

```
[TestFixture, Category("Oracle")]
```

and a

```
[TestFixture, Category("OracleOdbc")]
```

with a couple of tests which I would like to execute *separately* using `dotnet test`.

Here's what I tried after some Googling:

1. `dotnet test MyProject.csproj --where "cat==Oracle"` but this switch does not exists anymore.
2. `dotnet test MyProject.csproj --filter Category="Oracle"` yields 0 applicable tests: `No test is available in ...`.

Then, I've stumbled over [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests) and although it describes MSTest (and NUnit has the `CategoryAttribute` and not a `TestCategoryAttribute`), I've tried

3. `dotnet test MyProject.csproj --filter TestCategory="Oracle"`

Bingo. This time all "Oracle" tests were executed. But now comes the confusing part. If I run `dotnet test MyProject.csproj --filter TestCategory="OracleOdbc"`, **all** tests are being executed, including "Oracle" *and* "OracleOdbc". This makes me wonder if `TestCategroy` is the proper way to go for NUnit or if this is a bug.

I'm using .NET Command Line Tools (2.1.2) and the project references are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="TeamCity.VSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.0.7" />
```

BTW, I don't know if it matters but my test project is multi-targeting `netcoreapp2.0` and `net462`.

Comment: One thing I observe here is the single = sign for the category comparison. I employ nunit to run my tests from command line and they look like this: `nunit3-console.exe MyTestProject.dll --where "cat==myCategory"`

Comment: @Freya: thanks for spotting. I've fixed it. However, this question is about `dotnet test`. You are launching the `nunit3-console.exe` directly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might not be very helpful, but it seems to be working for me correctly.  I created the projects using the dotnet-cli.

First I installed the NUnit3 test adapter [instructions from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit).  This only needs to be run once on each machine so you don't need to do it again if you have already run it.

```
dotnet new -i NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template
```

Then I created my solution, created my test project and added the test project to the solution.

```
dotnet new sln -n Solution
dotnet new nunit -n TestProject -o tests\TestProject
dotnet sln add tests\TestProject\TestProject.csproj
```

Then I updated UnitTest1.cs to include two test fixtures, one with the category `Oracle` and one with the category `OracleOdbc`.

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("Oracle")]
    public class OracleTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void OracleTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    [Category("OracleOdbc")]
    public class OracleOdbcTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void OracleOdbcTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can specify which category I choose to run.

```
dotnet test tests/TestProject/TestProject.csproj --filter TestCategory="Oracle"
```

or

```
dotnet test tests/TestProject/TestProject.csproj --filter TestCategory="OracleOdbc"
```

both run only one test and the message shows it is the correct test that fails.

Using DotNet-Cli version 2.1.4 and NUnit3TestAdapter version 3.9.0

Comment: Which `NUnit` version did you use?

Comment: NUnit version also 3.9.0

Comment: How to specifigy multiple TestCategory? Is it possible to combine Oracle and OracleOdbc??
dotnet test --no-build --filter "TestCategory=Oracle&TestCategory=OracleOdbc" GherkinSuites.csproj

Answer (score 4):

In Nunit Framework, Category Attribute can be on the level of the Method.

**Example:**

```cs
public class NUnitTest 
    {
        [Test]
        [Category("CategoryA")] 
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("CategoryB")] 
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
        }

    }
```

and command is:

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=CategoryA     #Runs tests which are annotated with [Category("CategoryA")].
```

Also, there are many options on the level of method and others
For more details: [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests)

Answer (score 1):

There are now two options for filtering tests by category using `dotnet test`. You can use either dotnet.exe's built-in test filtering syntax, or the NUnit filtering syntax.

First add the NUnit3TestAdapter to your project using NuGet:

```
install-package nunit3testadapter -proj YourProject
```

You can then filter tests either like this:

```
dotnet.exe test .\ --test-adapter-path:. --filter TestCategory=Foo
```

or like this:

```
dotnet.exe test .\ --test-adapter-path:. -- NUnit.Where="cat=Foo"
```

[This blog post](https://blog.prokrams.com/2019/12/16/nunit3-filter-dotnet/) goes into further detail.

Answer (score -2):

You can also place a filter inside your test if you like enums like me:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Foo()
    {            
        // filter test
        switch (GlobalDefinitions.Category)
        {
                // OK Test
                case Category.Oracle:
                case Category.SQL:
                    break;

                // Do NOT test
                case Category.MongoDb:
                    Assert.Inconclusive();

                // Error
                default:
                    Assert.Fail("Not implemented case");
        }

        // perform test...

    }
```

Have the variable `GlobalDefinitions.Category` obtain the value from a resource file or whatever works best for you.

---

### Edit make the same code shorter with `Flags`

Create your categories

```
[Flags] // <-------------------- Important to shorten code 
public enum Category: int
{
    None = 0,
    Oracle = 1 << 0,
    SQL = 1 << 1,
    MongoDb = 1 << 2,

    // future categories        

    ALL = -1
}
```

// create your filter method

```
public static void Filter(Category category)
{
    if(GlobalDefinitions.Category.HasFlag(category) == false)
       Assert.Inconclusive(); // do not perform test

    // else perform test                         
}
```

// then create your test as:

```
[Test]
public void Test_Foo()
{ 
    Filter(Category.SQL | Category.MongoDb); // place filter (in this test we are testing for SQL and MongoDb

    // perform your test ...

}
```

Comment: Personally, I don't like mixing actual testing code with the concern of grouping and filtering them (which is an external concern IMHO).